# Substring(int,int) in java to consider string

Tags: java, string, global-variables, indexof, substr

I might be finding the complicated way around for this,but this is how it goes:
Got  a string stored in a global variable:
For eg:
This is the result of JSON string after reading from the REST API call stored in a global variable:
String Str= ["["b8f400be-b823-49c6-b0dd-5c97dc5d45e4"]"]

Now i need to split the string within the " " and the output should be only b8f400be-b823-49c6-b0dd-5c97dc5d45e4

I used substring,indexOf,lastIndexOf but unable to get a clear working solution in either case.What am i missing here?

```
str.substring(5, str.indexOf("\"", str.indexOf("\"") + 1))
 str.substring(5, str.substring.lastIndexOf("\"")-4);
```

Bumping into errors with the backslashes and double quotes,so used the `\"` method to extract the result but still does not work.

Since the parameters of substring only accepts (int,int) i am unable to provide a string there to retrieve,any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does the `str` variable actually contain?

Comment: I could just give you working code, or I could help you find what you [need](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to help yourself. Your toolbox has more that just a hammer. If the hammer won't do the job, grab a different tool. I would suggest looking into `lastIndexOf` for the second arg to `substring`. Note that you can search for String sequences, rather than just a char or a single character string. There are numerous other string methods that can help you accomplish your task in different ways.

Comment: @Unmitigated the str contains ["["b8f400be-b823-49c6-b0dd-5c97dc5d45e4"]"]

Comment: @MarsAtomic i ventured into all the string methods like substring,lastIndexOf ,search but none of them did the job and i keep getting error as:
Out of bounds exception,out of range -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding extra unnecessary logic. Its simply

`str.substring(5, str.lastIndexOf("\"")-3);`
or even

`str.substring(5, str.lastIndexOf("\\"));`

Also, here is how you properly assign/post a String variable - `String str = "["[\"b8f400be-b823-49c6-b0dd-5c97dc5d45e4\"]"]"`

At least that is what I am assuming based off of you using 5 as the first index of your substring. I originally thought you meant `String str = "[\"b8f400be-b823-49c6-b0dd-5c97dc5d45e4\"]"` What you posted was an array containing a single String value.